# How to say multiples of a name?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

What is the proper way to punctuate this sentence:

> According to www.website.com there are 1,234 **John Smiths** in the world.

or is it:

> According to www.website.com there are 1,234 **"John Smith"s** in the world.

or could it be:

> According to www.website.com there are 1,234 **John Smith's** in the world.

I hope someone can help me with this question because I cant seem to find the answer.

Comment: Google Books claims to have 141 instances of [Smiths in the phone book](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22smiths+in+the+phone+book%22), but only 7 [Smith's in the phone book](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22smith%27s+in+the+phone+book%22). I suggest you stick with the majority unless your context involves something that would make it difficult to parse, such as [There are a lot of O's in Korean phone books](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-last-names-family-names-that-are-only-one-letter).

Comment: Never, ever use the greengrocer's apostrophe to indicate plurals. It's so wrong it even has a name.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, how about for indicating the plurals of letters, as in, for example: "There are two *e*'s in *event*." Like FumbleFingers points to. Seems like an exception.

Comment: @AndrewLeach "Greengrocer's"? Quite polite. The Germans have a ruder word for it - Deppenapostroph (idiot's apostrophe).

Comment: There are 1,234 people named "John Smith" in the world.

Answer (score 2):

There is a perfectly conventional practice of using names as meta-linguistic count nouns which refer to people who bear that name. For example, we routinely say things like:

> - There are two Stellas in my class.
> - There are many Smiths in the directory.

Generally, we do not use quotation marks, italics or apostrophes. I feel that the practice is robust enough that you don't need them—in fact, using them is ugly.

That said, some style guides might disagree. They might suggest an alternative like:

> According to the Naming Organization, there are two million *people named "John Smith"* in the world.